# NameError: uninitialized constant "________"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm working on a homework assignment and when I attempt to run `rails db:migrate` I'm getting the error, `unitialized constant Cheeses`.

I believe something's misnamed.

Here are my files:

**straight_curdin/db/migrate/20180423222002_cheeses.rb**

```
class CreateCheeses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :cheeses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :milk_type
      t.string :image_url
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**straight_curdin/app/models/Cheese.rb**

```
class Cheese < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where does the migration file and its content come from? Did you run `rails generate`? If so, have you edited or renamed the file afterward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename the model's file name.

`straight_curdin/app/models/Cheese.rb` to `straight_curdin/app/models/cheese.rb`. as rails convention model's file name should be in small letters.

```
class Cheese < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Update: I figured it out. :|

The first line is supposed to read `class Cheeses.`

```
class Cheeses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :cheeses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :milk_type
      t.string :image_url
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, the name part of the filename, after the timestamp should match the class name, that’s how Rails knows which class to call. BTW, in rails, you name the file names all lower case, you model Cheese, should be in a file named cheese.rb, not Cheese.rb.

Comment: Also try to use Rails generate migration

Comment: It would probably have been a better idea to rename the migration to `20180423222002_create_cheeses.rb` because that migration file includes a migration that creates cheeses. Whereas a `Cheeses` class implies that it handles a collection of cheeses. You might need that name in your app later on.